# my function is not responding to the range it has

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have two questions
1) I wrote a function for odd and even numbers

```
def main():
  for num in range(65, 122):
    num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if (num %2==0):
      print("True")
    else:
      print("False")
main()
```

the functions still working tho but the problem is that whenever I enter a number that is less than 65 or greater than 122 the function still gives me an answer.

2.
so I have a function between the range of [65, 122] that should generate a list consisting of consecutive five numbers that are not multiplicable to 5.

```
def main():
  for i in range(65, 122):
    for n in range(len(i)):
      num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
      l=list()
      if (num%5!=0):
        l.append(n[:5])
      else:
        pass
main()
```

Comment: It. is not clear what you want to do and what you are asking

Comment: you're not restricting someone to a number between 65 and 122, you're just running the process that number of times since you just end up shadowing `num` by taking in user input

Comment: 1. Why you are reading user input inside a loop. Read about loop concept.

Comment: 2. There is some basic understand gaps. Please read about if else.

Comment: "the functions still working tho but the problem is that whenever I enter a number that is less than 65 or greater than 122 the function still gives me an answer." it is unclear why you would not expect that

Comment: `for` is a looping construct. You're telling it to loop through the numbers from 65 and to stop when it reaches 122.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets break down what your code is doing:

```
def main():
  for num in range(65, 122):            # Assigns num to be a 65. 
    num=int(input("Enter a number: "))  # Pauses. Overwrites num to a user input. 
    if (num %2==0):                     # Tests num is even and prints true. 
      print("True")
    else:
      print("False")                    # Starts loop over again. 
main()
```

Notice the problem here. You are performing a loop, but then pausing to ask the user for some input and then overwriting your loop variable. Hence, your loop is not being used. Moreover the values of your loop are constantly being overwritten and so your range(65,122) means nothing (except it will loop 57 times).

Here would be testing a number, printing and exiting.

```
def main():
  user_input = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if num%2==0:
    print(True)
  else:
    print(False)
main()
```

Here is adding a condition.

```
def main():
  user_input = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if 65 < user_input < 122:
    if num%2==0:
      print(True)
    else:
      print(False)
  else:
    print("You didn't provide a number in the right range.")
main()
```

Comment: oh that's why I was getting endless true/false answers, thanks man !

Answer (score 0):

1. For your question 1, usually `range()` can be express as a continuous num range, ex: 0 ~ 10.

   `for num in range(65, 122):` the variable `nums` will be assigned the value from 65 ~ 121. But after that, you reassign the `nums` as an input from the user. Therefore, it is not a way to constrain your input.

   You should use `if` to constrain the input value.

```py
if num >= 65 and num <= 122:
```

---

2. You can use the range to create a list, but you do not need the `input` anymore. And then you can implement more based on the items inside the list.

```py
l = list(range(65, 122+1))  # inclusive
l = [n for n in l if n % 5 == 0]
```

Comment: it works but I still need an input cause it depends on my what im gonna enter. for example if my input is 71 --> [71,72,73,74,77]